# Unable to concatenate variables in function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm running on SQL Server 2008 R2. I want to write a scalar function to concatenate the parts of the address and return the formatted result for display on the screen. But all I ever get back is the @Address variable--the city, state, zip, country is never added to the value. This should be simple; what am I doing wrong?

This is my scalar function:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
;

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnScreenAddress] (@Id INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(50)
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ScreenAddress VARCHAR(50), -- The return value
            @Address VARCHAR(64),
            @UnitNumber VARCHAR(16),
            @City VARCHAR(50),
            @State CHAR(2),
            @PostalCode VARCHAR(16),
            @CountryCode VARCHAR(16);

    SELECT  
        @Address = [Address],
        @UnitNumber = ISNULL([UnitNumber], ''),
        @City = [City],
        @State = [State],
        @PostalCode = [PostalCode],
        @CountryCode = ISNULL([CountryCode], '')
    FROM    
        [dbo].[LPAddress]
    WHERE   
        [ID] = @Id;

    SET @ScreenAddress = @Address;

    IF @City <> ''
    BEGIN
        SET @ScreenAddress = @ScreenAddress + ', ';
    END;

    SET @ScreenAddress = @ScreenAddress + @City;

    IF @State <> ''
    BEGIN
        SET @ScreenAddress = @ScreenAddress + ', ';
    END;

    SET @ScreenAddress = @ScreenAddress + @State;
    SET @ScreenAddress = @ScreenAddress + @PostalCode;
    SET @ScreenAddress = @ScreenAddress + @CountryCode;
    SET @ScreenAddress = LTRIM(RTRIM(@ScreenAddress));

    RETURN(@ScreenAddress);
END;
```

To test it, I enter the following command in a query window:

```
select 
    id, address, city, state, postalcode, countrycode, 
    dbo.fnScreenAddress(id) as [ScreenAddress]
from 
    lpaddress;
```

And I get this result set:

[image]

Comment: FYI, you can debug stored procedures in SSMS. You could step through your code and see where it goes wrong. See: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc646018.aspx

Comment: Is `lpaddress.address` a fixed length char field? Try setting `@ScreenAddress` to `MAX`.

Comment: @Malk I changed (at)ScreenAddress to VARCHAR(MAX) with no effect. But trimming each field that is used to build (at)ScreenAddress solved the problem. The fields are defined as CHAR(something) in the DB, so I think that is the genesis of the problem. I'll have to get the DBA to fix this (this is the real world), but in the meantime this will work. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: @JamesBalentine Consider posting your own solution to the question with code and explanation to logically close the question.

Comment: @DhruvJoshi - I made a rookie mistake above. I didn't think to trim the values before concatenating them, so the padding made it look like the concatenate operation was not working. That's not really worth posting as an answer. I like M.Ali 's solution below, and ended by implementing it (with the requisite trim until I can get the database fixed). Tak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A much simpler version would look something like.....

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnScreenAddress]
(
    @Id                 INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(4000)
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
BEGIN
        DECLARE @ScreenAddress VARCHAR(4000); -- The return value

SELECT  @ScreenAddress = 
    STUFF(  
        ISNULL( ', ' + NULLIF([Address]    , '')  , '')
      + ISNULL( ', ' + NULLIF([UnitNumber] , '')  , '')
      + ISNULL( ', ' + NULLIF([City]       , '')  , '')
      + ISNULL( ', ' + NULLIF([State]      , '')  , '')
      + ISNULL( ', ' + NULLIF([PostalCode] , '')  , '')
      + ISNULL( ', ' + NULLIF([CountryCode], '')  , '') , 1,2,'')
FROM    [dbo].[LPAddress]
WHERE   [ID] = @Id

        RETURN @ScreenAddress;
END;
```

**Important Note**

I wouldn't use a Scalar function for this purpose, Scalar functions are performance killers and specially in this specific case the function will be called as many times as many rows your select will return. Might just add the code of the function in your select query to get better performance.